# Ember cli - Models composed of multiple words and relationships (ember-data)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Currently developing an app using Ember-cli and having some dificulties with models with 2 words and relationships.

**Model residents-profile**

```
//models/residents-profile.js
DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    lastName: DS.attr('string'),
    picture: DS.attr('string'),
    phone: DS.attr('string'),
    gender: DS.attr('string'),
    residentsAccount: DS.belongsTo('residentsAccount')
}
```

** Model Residents-account **

```
//models/residents-account.js
DS.Model.extend({
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    password: DS.attr('string'),
    profileId: DS.attr('number'),
    residentsProfile: DS.belongsTo('residentsProfile', this.profileId),
});
```

**the model hook on the residents route:**

```
//routes/residents.js

    model: function() {
            return Ember.RSVP.hash({
              residentsProfile: this.store.find('residentsProfile'),
              residentsAccount: this.store.find('residentsAccount')
            })
    }
```

As soon as I try and fetch just the residents profile, i get an error "residents.index Cannot read property 'typeKey'"

But if I remove the relationship key from residents-profile and call only the residents profile the data is fetched correctly.

I'm using the RESTAdapter and a Restful API,

The models are being returned separately and the response from the server is as follows:

**GET /residentsProfile**
    {
        "residentsProfiles": [{
            "id": 20,
            "picture": null,
            "phone": null,
            "firstName": "Rocky",
            "lastName": "Balboa",
            "blockId": null,
            "unitId": null,
            "createdAt": "2014-09-17 19:54:28",
            "updatedAt": "2014-09-17 19:54:28",
            "residentsAccount": [5]
        }]
    }

**GET /residentsAccount**
    {
        "residentsAccounts": [{
            "id": 5,
            "email": "rocky@balboainc.me",
            "admin": false,
            "resident": true,
            "profileId": 20,
            "createdAt": "2014-09-17 19:54:29",
            "updatedAt": "2014-09-17 19:54:29",
            "residentsProfile": [20]
        }]
    }

**EDIT**

**Besides the changes proposed by @Kingpin2k, which were spot on, i used setupcontroller in the following way:**

```
setupController: function(controller, 
        controller.set('residentsAccount', models.residentsAccount);
        controller.set('residentsProfile', models.residentsProfile);
    }
```

Now everything works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three problems, both of your relationships should be async (since they aren't returned in the same response)

```
residentsAccount: DS.belongsTo('residentsAccount', {async: true})

residentsProfile: DS.belongsTo('residentsProfile', {async:true})
```

And both of the json response from them should be a single id, not an array

```
 {  
   "residentsProfiles":[  
     {  
     "id":20,
     "picture":null,
     "phone":null,
     "firstName":"Rocky",
     "lastName":"Balboa",
     "blockId":null,
     "unitId":null,
     "createdAt":"2014-09-17 19:54:28",
     "updatedAt":"2014-09-17 19:54:28",
     "residentsAccount":  5
     }
   ]
}
```

Lastly, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with `this.profileId` here, but it probably isn't doing what you think it is.  `this` in that scope is probably the window, meaning you're passing in undefined likely.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I just pasted whatever I had in my editor as I was (desperately) trying to debug. So definitely that was a mistake. I'm waiting for the backend guy to fix the api to test it and then mark your answer right.
Thank you very much for responding!